# raw_socket communication using udp protocol

Tags: c, unix

Am just beginner of this socket programming ...
i tried to make a UDP client_server program using SOCK_RAW .I can send message from the server part.But in client part am getting garbage values. And the receiving message packet size also different.Can U help me to do this client server program using SOCK_RAW.
I tried this client -server with eth0 & eht1,i tried to send 1 packet from eth0 to eth1 sending side is showing "OK" message.. but received data is garbage..
before i done normal client server program using UDP protocol.I got correct output from  normal udp client server .When i tried with SOCK_ROW its showing error in sending part.

Comment: Raw sockets are not UDP. If you want UDP, use SOCK_DGRAM.

Answer (score 2):

Make your life simpler and use [SOCK_DGRAM](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/udp.7.html) - Kernel will take care of datagram headers, you only need to provide valid IP address and data. It is user's responsibility to append (before transmitting) and parse (upon reception) UDP headers using SOCK_RAW.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you are seeing IP and UDP headers and calling them "garbage". That is what SOCK_ROW does. You should parse and skip protocol headers if you want to get to your message content while using SOCK_ROW.